# No keyboard on AlertDialog due to no focus on dialog box and still on background activity, how to fix?

Tags: java, android, dialog, keyboard, android-alertdialog

I have created a edittext inside a list, which is in a Dialog. Initially edittext is disaled, by tapping on another button in dialog, i make it enabled. I debug it further and found that focus is still on background activity, which causes keyboard to come on background activity.

JUST to point out: my edit text is numeric.

Tried multiple options but no outcome:

1. ```
   InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   keyboard.showSoftInput(null, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, null);
   ```

I found that keyboard is coming on background activity with this option after dialog open.

```
    splitDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Both options doesn't work to open keyboard on dialog.

I have also added    in editText box during XML generation.

My dialog code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.setTitle("Split Balance");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new SplitDialogCallback());
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    splitDialog.show();
```

Please give directions, as i am stuck due to this issue.

When i add one EditText in dialog directly instead of list view of dialog, things work fine, but if i remove it then again same issue. Not able to understand why focus not going if edit text in list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android keyboard is quite intelligent that you would not need to toggle their input in this manner.Try this once.

remove this:

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.showSoftInput(null, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, null);
```

and

```
splitDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

then i'd suggest using a custom dialog layout instead of a view.Try this.

```
    final Dialog splitDialog = new Dialog(this);
     splitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.abc_action_bar_decoryour_dialog_layout);
    //Button that you want to toggle the editText enabled
    Button btn = splitDialog.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText =splitDialog.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
            editText.setEnabled(true);
            editText.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    splitDialog.show();
```

This IMHO is a better way to use a dialog,it gives you more freedom esp since you're anyways using a custom dialog layout.

I know this does not tell why your method is not working..but its merely a better handled solution

Comment: Thanks, but as EditText is in listview inside dialog, so how to find buttEditTexton, as there can be multiple rows in a list view. I have added a work around by adding one dummy edittext with height and weight 0, so that android think there is a edit text in dialog and opens a keyboard. But that is a not a proper solution.

Comment: are you using a custom list view?then i'd suggest adding the button on click listener in the list view adapter,the code would remain the same.I current understand that your list item has a button and an edittext each.Am i correct?

Comment: yes, you are right. I am currently not using Custom list view, but adding a custom view in list view through a separate XML file. Thanks for help, will try this solution.